# HTML5 Web SQL tx.executeSql UNION example

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I am trying to query information from two different tables and want to combine them into one result. The query below fails. I also want to know if you could just print out all data in a row, rather than accessing each individual data in a row using results.rows.item(i).-some field name-.

```
db.transaction(function (tx) { 
                tx.executeSql('SELECT firstName, lastName, gender, photo FROM DEMO UNION SELECT medication, notes FROM VITAL', [], function (tx, results) { 
                    var len = results.rows.length, i; 
                    msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>"; 
                    document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg; 

                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
                        msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).firstName + "</b></p>"; 
                        document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg; 
                    } 
                }, null); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use left join instead

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT firstName, lastName, gender, photo, medication, VITAL.notes FROM DEMO LEFT JOIN VITAL ON DEMO.rowid=VITAL.rowid', [], function (tx, results) {
```